# Select with optgroup in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have the following data right now:

```
[
    {
        "value": "G1-1",
        "text": "One",
        "optgroup": "Group 1
    },
    {
        "value": "G1-2",
        "text": "Two",
        "optgroup": "Group 1"
    },
    {
        "value": "G1-3",
        "text": "Three",
        "optgroup": "Group 1"
    },
    {
        "value": "G1-4",
        "text": "Four",
        "optgroup": "Group 1"
    },
    {
        "value": "G2-1",
        "text": "One",
        "optgroup": "Group 2"
    },
    {
        "value": "G2-2",
        "text": "Two",
        "optgroup": "Group 2"
    },
    {
        "value": "G2-3",
        "text": "Three",
        "optgroup": "Group 3"
    },
    {
        "value": "G2-4",
        "text": "Four",
        "optgroup": "Group 4"
    }
]
```

This data I pass as options in a simple Dropdown component that I created as follows:

```
const SelectInputRound = ({defaultOption, name, value, onChange, options}) => {
    return (
        <select
            id={name}
            className="inputSelectRound form-control override-fc"
            name={name}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}>
            <option className="defaultOption" value="">{defaultOption}</option>
            {
                options.map((option) => {
                    return <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.text}</option>;
                })
            }
        </select>
    );
};
```

My problem now is I'm not sure how to group my options and pass it to my control such that I can have optgroups show up in my component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My problem now is I'm not sure how to group my options and pass it to my control such that I can have optgroups show up in my component.

Before passing the data to your `Dropdown` component, you could transform it first to group the data accordingly. For example, like this.

```js
const options = [
  {
    value: "G1-1",
    text: "One",
    optgroup: "Group 1"
  },
  {
    value: "G2-2",
    text: "Two",
    optgroup: "Group 2"
  },
  {
    value: "G2-3",
    text: "Three",
    optgroup: "Group 3"
  },
  {
    value: "G2-4",
    text: "Four",
    optgroup: "Group 4"
  }
];
const groupedOptions = {};
options.forEach(option => {
  if (!groupedOptions[option.optgroup]) groupedOptions[option.optgroup] = [];
  groupedOptions[option.optgroup].push({
    value: option.value,
    text: option.text
  });
});
console.log(groupedOptions);
```

However you have to modify your `Dropdown` component as well so that instead of expecting `options` as one of the `props`, it should expect a group of options instead.

```js
const renderOptions = options => {
  return options.map(option => {
    return (
      <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
        {option.text}
      </option>
    );
  });
};

const SelectInputRound = ({
  defaultOption,
  name,
  value,
  onChange,
  groupedOptions
}) => {
  return (
    <select
      id={name}
      className="inputSelectRound form-control override-fc"
      name={name}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
    >
      {Object.keys(groupedOptions).map((group, index) => {
        return (
          <optgroup key={index} label={group}>
            {renderOptions(groupedOptions[group])}
          </optgroup>
        );
      })}
    </select>
  );
};
```

See working example [here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/8z319o6yvl)

Comment: This is such a detailed answer. Thanks a lot for taking your time out to put it up so nicely.